# Notificador de qualquer evento que o usuário realizar no sistema

Tags: java, aplicação-web, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

Estou usando o Framework Spring para o java e gostaria de criar posso criar um tipo de aviso, `<scan>`, que mostra na tabela que uma nova linha foi adicionada (essa linha vem do banco de dados), e ao clicar nela sumir dando a entender que a linha foi vista, como se fosse um notificador de Facebook por exemplo, mas cada usuário tem o seu, ou seja, avisar para cada um que existe uma nova linha.

Comment: Sugiro reescrever de forma mais clara qual é o seu problema e como você está tentando resolvê-lo, está muito confuso da forma que está escrita.

Comment: E agora ? ja alterei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagino que voce precise criar algo utilizando aspectos do Spring. Mais informações [aqui](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-aop-aspectj-annotation-example/)

Com AspectJ, voce pode monitorar algum ponto da sua aplicação e executar processamentos antes, durante ou depois conforme as anotações @Before, @After, @AfterReturning...

Esse tipo de programação é muito utilizado pra logs de aplicação, mas pode ser perfeitamente aplicado no seu caso.

Com o AspectJ configurado, voce pode executar uma ação @After no seu método de persistência da linha de tabela, e persistir alguma coisa em uma tabela de avisos associada aos usuários.